# Message Recaptcha with react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby, react-hook-form

Below the Gatsby form is working, but I would like to know how I can display the message if the reCaptcha is not checked / selected after sending, using the react-hook-form?

```
import React from "react"
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"

import ReCAPTCHA from "react-google-recaptcha"

const IndexPage = () => { 
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm()
  
  const onSubmit = (data) => { 
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data))       
  }

  const onChange = (value) => {
    console.log("Recaptcha Value:",value)
  }

  return(
    <>
      <h1>Contact</h1>
        <form method="post" action="/" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <label>First Name</label>
          <input name="example" ref={register({ required: true })} />
          {errors.example && <small>This field is required</small>}
          <br/>
          <label>Last Name</label>
          <input name="exampleRequired" ref={register({ required: true })} />
          {errors.exampleRequired && <small>This field is required</small>}
          <ReCAPTCHA
            sitekey="6LdSWKgZAAAAAKrrp6GFXldEv0I4vqO3yWrTkuNV"
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
        <button type="reset">Reset</button>
      </form>
    </>
  )
}

export default IndexPage
```

Comment: To clarify - you're asking how to display an error message if the captcha is not selected (and block the form submit)?

Comment: Maybe this can be helpful: https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/1001